# Centering background image javascript slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this up and running and was wondering if you can start the image in the center rather than to the left. Seems if I manipulate the css it doesn't center it so wondered if it needs something within the javascript. Or in fact even to select a specific starting point within the image. My javascript knowledge is not the greatest though...

here's what I'm talking about

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/MvRdD/890/

Comment: you could scroll right 50% of the image width without animation at pageload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `scrollLeft()` function onload to scroll the container to the center. Try this:

```
var center = $('#content').width()/2 - scrollWrapper.width()/2
scrollWrapper.scrollLeft(center);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/922/

Answer (score 0):

The following will center the image, with no scrollbars visible:

```
newleft =$('body').width()/2 - $('#content').width()/2;
$('#content').offset({left: newleft});
```

Unfortunately it's not perfect as it doesn't let you scroll to leftest part by pressing your 'Left' button, I'm trying to see if this can be improved but nonetheless this can be useful for your as fiddling upon it.

See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/zMxz9/)

Comment: Ah thank you but, my scroll bars are non existent anywho... ihave some css3 buttons to navigate along with the mousewheel scroll and mousedrag

Comment: The solution David posted has scrollbars visible, I thought you were looking for a solution without them, like your original fiddle.

Comment: @Nelson: true, I left them visible in the fiddle just to debug. However, the code I posted does not affect scrollbar visibility.

Comment: Of course, just when I thought this was all sussed it doesn't work on touch devices... I'm looking at how the buttons can be detected on touch devices but there doesn't seem to be much about or I am looking in the wrong place (I tried Google)... Is there a way of detedctng the buttons easily? I don't want to have to find another entire image panner!

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing its the mouse events that are messing this up?!

Comment: Anybody know how to swap out mouse events for touch events? Or detect a phone or tablet and convert to touch events?